# How to use the gcc installed in macports?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, macports

I installed gcc 4.6. from macports (for support of C++0x). But when I check the  'gcc --version` it is showing older version. How to use the newer gcc installed by macports?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update GCC on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837992/update-gcc-on-osx)

Comment: Also see [Using the Right Compiler](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/UsingTheRightCompiler) on the MacPorts wiki.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I remember it being something like `g++-mp-4.6`. I believe it's enough to set the environment variable `CXX` to that.

Comment: that worked. is there a way to use it by default so that I dont have to change all make files.

Comment: Why is this accept as best answer while Raim's answer is the correct one?

Answer (score 114):

You can control the symlink in `/opt/local/bin/gcc` by using `port select`. You can see available version using `port select --list gcc`. Anything listed with mp- as prefix refers to MacPorts' own port, gcc42 and llvm-gcc42 refer to the compilers shipped with Xcode by Apple.

Example from my system:

```
$ port select --list gcc
Available versions for gcc:
    gcc42
    llvm-gcc42
    mp-gcc45
    none (active)
$ sudo port select --set gcc mp-gcc45
Password:
Selecting 'mp-gcc45' for 'gcc' succeeded. 'mp-gcc45' is now active.
```

After that, either open a new terminal window or issue `hash -r` to make bash recognize the change.

Comment: I've done this, and when I type `port select --list gcc`, it says that mp-gcc47 is active.  However, when I do `gcc --version`, it still says it's using version 4.2... I've tried opening a new terminal and typing `hash -r`.  Any idea why?

Comment: Check your PATH, maybe there is some other gcc (or a symlink) before /opt/local/bin. Could also be some alias or function in your shell. Try 'type -a gcc' to see what bash uses for the lookup.

Comment: When I do `type -a gcc`, I get two lines: "gcc is /usr/bin/gcc
gcc is /opt/local/bin/gcc".  When I print my PATH, I get ".:/opt/local/var/macports:/usr/local/bin:/sw/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/hallamsoft:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin".  Sorry, I'm not totally sure what either of these mean, but I did put Macports first in my path.

Comment: Sorry, but you certainly did not put MacPorts first. Watch the paths closely, you have /opt/local/var/macports near the front, but that will not actually contain any binaries. /opt/local/bin follows later in the list, after /usr/bin. That is why bash is picking up gcc from there.

(Also you should never list "." in your PATH, it's a harmful vulnerability to do so).

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure macports' path comes first in your `$PATH`. Or use `gcc-mp-4.6` or something like that.

Comment: @jli, the one from `/usr/bin`? Doesn't sound like a good idea :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker you still need to set the active gcc as stated above.

Comment: This was my problem, and a good possible answer to the question. I had already used port select and was puzzled when the gcc --version always reported the old version. It was totally a $PATH problem.