# How to enable a MacPorts-installed gcc4.7 (and libstdc++) in Xcode 4.5?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction

I have installed gcc4.7 (and hopefully the related version of stdlibc++ with it) through MacPorts, and I now need to enable it so that I can use it within Xcode (which is currently version 4.5). Does anybody know how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use "select" command of MacPorts.

> port select --list gcc

will show the list of installed gcc(s).

> sudo port select gcc

will activate installed gcc.  should be specified one of that list. (ex. mp-gcc47

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8372496/1055604) answer for specific commandline output...

Comment: As far as I can tell, this does not update Xcode to use the macports gcc