# Is there xgboost 0.6 conda installation package for python 2.7 on mac?

Tags: installation, anaconda, xgboost

This [link stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315156/how-to-install-xgboost-in-python-on-mac) provides the xgboost 0.4 installation method
`conda install -c aterrel xgboost=0.4.0`.
It is OK to use, but I would like to look for the latest xgboost package(maybe 0.6 as far as I know). I tried the pip and brew method, but it seems complex for me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Installing xgboost on mac is pretty straightforward, all you gotta do is follow the documentation on the official website: http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install -c biconda xgboost=0.6a2
```