# How to install xgboost for python3.6 in mac

Tags: python, macos, gcc, xgboost

I have followed following method [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315156/how-to-install-xgboost-in-python-on-macos) to install in mac.

When I run following command, I get output `gcc 7.2.0 already installed`

`brew install gcc`

After that I config.mk file in make folder to following, because I have 7.2.0 gcc installed.

`export CC = gcc-7`

`export CXX = g++-7`

I run following command `make clean_all && make -j4` once I change config.mk file is changed.

Then I run `cd python-package; python setup.py install`.

If without closing terminal i go to python3.6, where I can access xgboost without problem. However, when I switch to different terminal, I am getting following error

```
OSError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/5/libgomp.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Any ideas why it is happening, how to fix it ?

Comment: Check this page.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315156/how-to-install-xgboost-in-python-on-macos

Answer (score -2):

```
$ brew install gcc@5
$ pip install xgboost
```

It worked for me.[xgboost==0.6a2]

Comment: Says gcc@5 is deprecated