# Error when importing XGBoost on Apple M1?

Tags: macos, machine-learning, xgboost, apple-m1

**Has anyone figured out how to make XGboost work with Apple M1?**

I have tried multiple things to fix it, but it does not work.

*I have tried reinstalling it; pip and pip3 and python -m pip and conda install; brew install limpomp; brew install gcc@8; Downloading source code and compiling locally.*

It seems XGboost does not work on Apple M1.

**Here is the error, this occurs when I import xgboost in my script:**

```
XGBoostError: XGBoost Library (libxgboost.dylib) could not be loaded.
Likely causes:
  * OpenMP runtime is not installed (vcomp140.dll or libgomp-1.dll for Windows, libomp.dylib for Mac OSX, libgomp.so for Linux and other UNIX-like OSes). Mac OSX users: Run `brew install libomp` to install OpenMP runtime.
  * You are running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit OS
Error message(s): ['dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/envs/msc-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.dylib, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib\n  Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/envs/msc-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.dylib\n  Reason: image not found']
```

Answer (score 7):

i'd got the same issue on MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) with chip Apple M1, fortunately after of hours of some researches i got the solution, you just follow the following instruction:

```
brew install libomp
conda install -c conda-forge py-xgboost
```

Comment: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:  - py-xgboost

Answer (score 4):

https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/xgboost-on-apple-m1/2004/8

[How to install xgboost in python on MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315156/how-to-install-xgboost-in-python-on-macos)

A combination of the answer from cherry (first) and Christoffer (second) work for me with miniforge interpreter:

> Make sure gcc-11 (and g+±11) is installed, if not do so with
>
> ```
> brew install gcc@11
> brew install cmake
> ```
>
> Then, do the following

```
    git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
    mkdir xgboost/my_build
    cd xgboost/my_build
    CC=gcc-11 CXX=g++-11 cmake ..
    make -j4
    cd ../python_package
   /Users/xx/miniforge3/envs/MLEnv/bin/python setup.py install
```

> With the path to you miniforge venv

Comment: directory 'python_package' does not exist

Comment: On my machine, the folder was python-package

Answer (score 0):

I put Terminal in Rosetta mode first before installing brew. This way I'm essentially running intel version of the packages. I provided more details in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/oscarychen/3462e5b957a6d6159d793bd174a86c1b).