# PackagesNotFoundError: py-xgboost-gpu

Tags: python, installation, gpu, conda, xgboost

I'm trying to install `py-xgboost-gpu` on a Mac as XGBoost instructs on the [website](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#conda) but I'm getting a `PackagesNotFoundError`

I'm running

```
conda install -c conda-forge py-xgboost-gpu
```

and getting

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - py-xgboost-gpu
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Probably worth looking into these: 
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#conda
https://machinelearningmastery.com/install-xgboost-python-macos/

Comment: Using Mac OSX and just tried `brew install libomp` but still getting the error, any idea why?

Comment: This post may also help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315156/how-to-install-xgboost-in-python-on-macos

Answer (score 0):

GPU builds are for CUDA, which means NVIDIA hardware and Apple doesn't use that in their products. Hence, there is no such support. Instead, follow the instructions for CPU:

```
conda install -c conda-forge py-xgboost-cpu
```

Really, one shouldn't even need to specify:

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

includes `py-xgboost` and on macOS it defaults to `-cpu` version.