# Qscintilla make error : "Qt requires C++11 support"

Tags: macos, qt, c++11, qscintilla

I am trying to compile Qscintilla 2.9.3 (obtained [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/qscintilla/download)) on mac (OS X 10.11.6), but the make step fails with the following error :

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -w -fPIC -DQSCINTILLA_MAKE_DLL -DSCINTILLA_QT -DSCI_LEXER -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_MACEXTRAS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -I../include -I../lexlib -I../src -I/Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtMacExtras.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-g++ -F/Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib -o qsciscintilla.o qsciscintilla.cpp
>   In file included from qsciscintilla.cpp:23:
>   In file included from ./Qsci/qsciscintilla.h:29:
>   In file included from /Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QByteArray:1:
>   In file included from /Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbytearray.h:44:
>   In file included from /Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qrefcount.h:43:
>   In file included from /Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qatomic.h:41:
>   In file included from /Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qglobal.h:1145:
>   In file included from /Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qatomic.h:46:
>   /Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:61:4: error:
>        "Qt requires C++11 support"
>   #  error "Qt requires C++11 support"
>       ^
>   /Applications/Utilities/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:90:13: error:
>        unknown type name 'QAtomicOps'
>      typedef QAtomicOps Ops;

Following other questions on the subject, I have added

```
\# With C++11 support  
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4){      
CONFIG += c++11  
} else {  
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x  
}
```

in the qscintilla.pro file, to no avail.

This [thread](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54257) seems to show a similar problem. It was solved by suppressing an `-ansi` flag in a dependency, which prevented the use of c++11. However I do not see such a flag in the log above.

Do you have an idea as to what could cause that problem ?

I have QMake version 3.0 and Qt 5.7.

Comment: what compiler do you use and what version has it?

Comment: According to the log above g++ is called. g++ --version gives the following :
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: I don't really see the gcc version number here. If the '4.2.1' is the version number you gcc has no c++11.

Comment: The compiler is clang, which replaces gcc on macs ([see this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410587/how-to-find-gcc-version-on-mac))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the remarks above regarding the compiler used, I found on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408849/how-can-i-use-c-11-features-in-clang) that in order to use c++11 with clang/llvm on Mac, it is necessary to also use the library -stdlib=libc++ instead of the old libstdc++.

The problem was thus solved by adding

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
```

to the .pro file.