# How to build mesos on Mavericks

Tags: osx-mavericks, mesos

I cloned from git:

```
git clone git://git.apache.org/mesos.git
```

and also had done

```
brew install autoconf automake libtool
```

Then trying to follow the "Getting started" at

http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/

And specifically :

```
Only if running from source code cloned from git, 
run ./bootstrap otherwise skip to step 3
```

So I ran

```
./bootstrap
```

Here is a trimmed output of the results.  I did not see any ERRORS as such but plenty of WARNings.  End result exited with 1 and no configure script was generated:

```
autoreconf: configure.ac: adding subdirectory 3rdparty/stout to autoreconf
autoreconf: Entering directory `3rdparty/stout'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/bin/autoconf --warnings=all
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Autoheader
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --no-force --warnings=all
configure.ac:10: installing './missing'
autoreconf: Leaving directory `3rdparty/stout'
autoreconf: running: glibtoolize --copy
glibtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
glibtoolize: copying file `./ltmain.sh'
..
glibtoolize: copying file `m4/ltversion.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
..
m4/libtool.m4:694: LT_OUTPUT is expanded from...
configure.ac:28: the top level
configure.ac:87: warning: The macro `AC_LANG_SAVE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:87: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/lang.m4:128: AC_LANG_SAVE is expanded from...
m4/acx_pthread.m4:363: ACX_PTHREAD is expanded from...
configure.ac:87: the top level
configure.ac:87: warning: The macro `AC_LANG_C' is obsolete.
configure.ac:87: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/c.m4:72: AC_LANG_C is expanded from...
m4/acx_pthread.m4:363: ACX_PTHREAD is expanded from...
configure.ac:87: the top level
configure.ac:87: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:87: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2688: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
m4/acx_pthread.m4:363: ACX_PTHREAD is expanded from...
configure.ac:87: the top level
configure.ac:87: warning: The macro `AC_LANG_RESTORE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:87: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/lang.m4:134: AC_LANG_RESTORE is expanded from...
m4/acx_pthread.m4:363: ACX_PTHREAD is expanded from...
configure.ac:87: the top level
configure.ac:21: installing './ar-lib'
configure.ac:21: installing './compile'
configure.ac:8: installing './config.guess'
configure.ac:8: installing './config.sub'
configure.ac:18: installing './missing'
automake: warnings are treated as errors
3rdparty/Makefile.am:71: warning: source file '$(GTEST)/src/gtest-all.cc' is in a subdirectory,
3rdparty/Makefile.am:71: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
automake: warning: possible forward-incompatibility.
automake: At least a source file is in a subdirectory, but the 'subdir-objects'
automake: automake option hasn't been enabled.  For now, the corresponding output
automake: object file(s) will be placed in the top-level directory.  However,
automake: this behaviour will change in future Automake versions: they will
automake: unconditionally cause object files to be placed in the same subdirectory
automake: of the corresponding sources.
automake: You are advised to start using 'subdir-objects' option throughout your
automake: project, to avoid future incompatibilities.
3rdparty/Makefile.am:71: warning: source file '$(GMOCK)/src/gmock-all.cc' is in a subdirectory,
3rdparty/Makefile.am:71: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
3rdparty/Makefile.am:61: warning: source file '$(RY_HTTP_PARSER)/http_parser.c' is in a subdirectory,
3rdparty/Makefile.am:61: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
3rdparty/Makefile.am:118: warning: source file '$(STOUT)/tests/bytes_tests.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
..
3rdparty/Makefile.am:118: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
3rdparty/Makefile.am:118: warning: source file '$(STOUT)/tests/flags_tests.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
3rdparty/Makefile.am:118: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
..
3rdparty/Makefile.am:146: warning: source file '$(STOUT)/tests/proc_tests.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
3rdparty/Makefile.am:146: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
3rdparty/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
Makefile.am:29: warning: source file 'src/latch.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
Makefile.am:29: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
Makefile.am:29: warning: source file 'src/pid.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
Makefile.am:29: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
Makefile.am:29: warning: source file 'src/process.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
Makefile.am:29: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
Makefile.am:29: warning: source file 'src/statistics.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
Makefile.am:29: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
..
Makefile.am:101: warning: source file 'src/tests/shared_tests.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
Makefile.am:101: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
Makefile.am:101: warning: source file 'src/tests/statistics_tests.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
Makefile.am:101: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
Makefile.am:101: warning: source file 'src/tests/time_tests.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
Makefile.am:101: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

Comment: Which version of automake are you using? `automake --version`

Comment: -bash-3.2$ automake --version
automake (GNU automake) 1.9.6
Written by Tom Tromey <tromey@redhat.com>.

Comment: You will have to downgrade due to incompatibilities of Mesos with recent automake releases. Anything below 1.14 will do. I am using automake 1.13.4 and it works fine. This is unfortunately true for many projects, automake is a common versioning-hell trap.

Comment: Thanks for that tip (upvoted), I will look into this in about 24hrs

Comment: Make sure you check ssorallen's answer as that one wraps it neatly up. In fact, the best thing to do is to check the `docs/getting-started.md` document as it has a neat little overview on how to get things working on OSX.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Mesos team updated the ["Getting Started" document](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#building-mesos-on-mac-os-x-mavericks) with instructions on building and running Mesos on Mavericks.

[GCC was replaced with Clang on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535422/os-x-10-9-gcc-links-to-clang), and so you first have to install GCC 4.7+. You can use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install it (**Note: installing GCC takes a loooong time**):

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install gcc48
```

This is the gist of getting started on Mavericks:

```
# Make sure you have the right versions of automake and GCC.
# For example:
$ automake --version
automake (GNU automake) 1.12.6
...

$ aclocal --version
aclocal (GNU automake) 1.12.6
...

$ gcc-4.8 --version
gcc-4.8 (GCC) 4.8.1
...

# Follow bootstrap steps above.

# Configure and build.
$ mkdir build
$ cd build

# The prepending CC and CXX will select custom compilers to build Mesos with.
$ CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 ../configure
```

Comment: I will look at this within 12 hours, in meantime it looks quite helpful and I have upvoted.

Comment: I added a note and a link about why installing GCC is necessary. Let me know if this answer works for you.

Comment: thanks for the further detail, i did not have opportunity yet to try this - another day probably.

Comment: @javadba For the clang (vs. gcc) issue I am excited to tell you that there is a mesos version upcoming that is fully clang compatible. So in a not too distant future, you may uninstall gcc again :D

Comment: Adding to my comment on clang, the current development version (0.17.0) does compile perfectly fine without any issues on Mavericks - only remaining issue is automake that needs to be manually installed after getting Xcode's commandline tools setup.

Comment: I got completely sidetracked. I will vote this as the best answer though I did not yet perform the steps.