# LLVM Clang 5.0 explicit in copy-initialization error

Tags: c++, macos, boost, g++, llvm

I'm trying to compile an open source project on OSX that has only been tested on Linux.

```
$: g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-da
```

I'm trying to compile with the following command line options

```
g++ -MMD -Wall -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-variable -ftemplate-depth=1024 -I /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0/include/boost/ -g -O3 -c level.cpp -o obj-opt/level.o
```

I am seeing several errors that look like this:

```
./square.h:39:70: error: chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization
      int strength = 0, double flamability = 0, map<SquareType, int> constructions = {}, bool ticking = false);
```

The project states the following are requirements for the Linux setup. How can I confirm I'm making that?

```
gcc-4.8.2
git
libboost 1.5+ with libboost-serialize
libsfml-dev 2+ (Ubuntu ppa that contains libsfml 2: )
freeglut-dev
libglew-dev
```

Comment: Downvoted without any feedback. Very helpful

Comment: This is not a question about programming, so StackOverflow is the wrong place to ask.  Try SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: Disagree. Compilation is part of programming.

However, the relevant chunk of the source code is probably going to help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project requires you to compile with gcc-4.8.2 , but your g++ is using clang, which is a different compiler.

Install gcc-4.8.2 or above, and use it to compile your project

```
$ sudo port install gcc49
```

Comment: For the record here I used `homebrew` to install `gcc49`

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19535525/93212