# I upgrade mac os 10.6 to 10.9.4 , gcc can not work ,can anyone help me?

Tags: macos, gcc

compile error like this:

fatal error : 'sys/types.h' file not found .

and a test application with main function,error like this:

error : unkonwn type name '__darwin_off_t'

ps : I hace installed the xcode command tool ..

Comment: 10.6 to 10.9 is a big jump.  Its quite possible system files moved around a bit.  How did you install gcc previously (brew? macports? command line tools?) Have you *reinstalled* gcc and Xcode after the upgrade?

Comment: I had reintall xcode ,and command line tools. I do nothing with gcc .

Comment: With 10.8, gcc on OSX isn't gcc anymore - its a front to clang (see [OS X 10.9 gcc links to clang](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19535422/289086)).  If that hasn't been updated, things may break quite significantly. If that hasn't been updated with the command line tools install, you likely have some troubleshooting to do there. If you want *gcc* and not a front to clang, you will need to install it from an alternate source.  It may help to add the output of `gcc -v` to the question.

Comment: and gcc is installed with xcode .

Comment: You'll need to install the command line tools from XCode.  There are questions about that, either here or on the [Apple](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) site, or on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: @MichaelT   I reintall gcc with brew, and it does not work. And the version is clang-503.0.40. Can calng compile the GNU project whih a Makefile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much !

The question solved finally by reinstall gcc .

The download address : https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads

I use the version : GCC Installer for OSX 10.6.x