# Trying to find out what specific atom package changed terminal functionality

Tags: macos, terminal, g++, atom-editor

I installed Atom over the weekend and installed some packages to make it more functional.  After installing some of the packages, I ran terminal and ran a g++ command to compile some software and the error codes and display now look a lot different.  Its actually much more clear in this form what the issues are, but that's besides the point.  I'm wondering if anyone might know which package might've caused this sort of change?  The easiest thing to do would be be to list all of the packages I downloaded, but I downloaded quite a few and ended up uninstalling some, so I don't even have a definitive list of what they could be.  I'm not even 100 percent positive that it was an Atom package that changed the g++ output, but I don't recall it looking this way before.  What I'm referring to is the error message and the green arrow pointing to the exact issue.  I don't believe this was the way the output looked before after trying to compile a program with issues.

[image]

I realize this is a vague request to track down, but if anyone has any idea which package might've changed the way g++ outputs errors to the screen, that would be awesome.

I'm ultimately trying to figure out how to remove whatever it was that changed it and go back to the original output, so if anyone has any suggests for maybe reverting the functionality, I would try that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I've spent a majority of my time compiling in the linux shell via g++ that I never really paid attention to the the way the error messages look in mac terminal when using g++.

After a bit of digging, [I found that g++ is using clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535422/os-x-10-9-gcc-links-to-clang).  After looking at [the clang documentation for "Expressive Diagnostics,"](http://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html) I've come to find that these sort of markups (what Clang devs are calling "Caret Diagnostics and Range Highlighting") are normal and standard, not installed by Atom.  I must've drawn that conclusion randomly out of paranoia, after installing packages and packages for Atom and only then, noticing the difference in error output between Linux shell g++ and Mac Terminal g++.

A poster named "Adam" suggests that ["Homebrew"](http://brew.sh) is an easier way of getting Terminal to revert back to using GCC instead of Clang, which should be close to what I'm used to with the Linux shell experience with g++