# GCC 4.4.4 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gcc

I have the latest Xcode package downloaded on my computer, however, I need to install GCC 4.4.4 I am currently running gcc 4.2, which I assume the latest version of what Apple is rolling out.

What do you suggest I should do?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update GCC on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837992/update-gcc-on-osx)

Comment: Why do you need 4.4.4? It's almost definitely a bad idea to install it on Mac OSX: http://superuser.com/a/125075/31165

Comment: For Ben Hocking: gcc 4.2.1 not support c++00 standart, global optimizations wich can reduce size of binary, for example. It's pain to develop modern cross-platform application.