# Change GCC Version to 4.7 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gcc, g++

On OS X, I currently have a couple versions of gcc installed. Whenever I use `gcc -v` or `g++ -v`, it tells me: `gcc version 4.2.1`. I have installed gcc 4.7, though, in the interest of taking advantage of C++11. How can I change it so that gcc/g++ points to 4.7 instead of 4.2.1?

EDIT: I have homebrew, not macports.

Comment: do you use macport? is port-select ok?

Comment: I use homebrew, unfortunately. The only other solution I could find pointer to macports.

Comment: i have not use homebrew. i think you can use abs path somehow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tricky question if we don’t know the full path of the other installs. But basically you could change the $PATH order in your local user `.profile` settings. So let’s say your 4.7 install is in `/usr/local/bin/` & we know the Apple default version is in `/usr/bin/` then edit your `.profile` so `/usr/local/bin/` comes before `/usr/bin/` in $PATH order.

Default should be something like this:

> export PATH=/usr/bin:**/usr/local/bin**:[etc, etc, etc]

Adjusted should be something like this:

> export PATH=**/usr/local/bin**:/usr/bin:[etc, etc, etc]

There is a way to force this change systemwide for all users, but I do not recommend that. Don’t muck around with the deeper—and often non-standard—ways Apple implements a *nix environment. Keep it local to your user.

**EDIT:** [Check the discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837992/update-gcc-on-osx) to see if any solutions offered can help you. It does seem like installing `gcc_select` via MacPorts would be the cleanest solution.

Comment: I think 4.7 is in `/usr/bin/` , so it's not different than the default you specify. Furthermore, I used unlink on the gcc that was being used before and it disappeared from `/usr/bin/` folder so I think that might support this? So how can I now link gcc-4.7 to gcc?

Comment: As I'm currently on homebrew, I feel like switching to macports could be a big pain. But I'm looking into it as I'm not overly attached to homebrew.
Also, all installs seem to be located right in /usr/bin/, does this help?

Comment: So gcc and g++ currently exist as links to gcc-4.7 and g++-4.7 respectively, and this is in /usr/bin. Also, /usr/bin is at the start of $PATH. What do I need to do so I can type gcc or g++ anywhere to be able to use it?

Answer (score 7):

I think you can do something like this.
Go to `/usr/bin`

Assume you have install the `gcc-4.7` using home brew in mavericks.
then type:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo mv gcc gcc_mavs
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.7.0/bin/gcc-4.7 gcc
```

After this type to verify if you have select the right gcc compiler.

`gcc -v`

Answer (score 0):

I found a very good tutorial online. Although, it is a little bit older (describes the process for gcc 3.2) the same general approach can still be used 
http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/install_gcc.html