# enum class in c++ can not compile in Mac, while works in Windows

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, enums, g++, enum-class

it seems there are some problems with my g++ 4.2 compiler in my Mac. I defined a enum class as follows.

```
enum class Suit {CLUBS,SPADES,HEARTS,DIAMONDS};
```

It can compile and run in VS2013 but failed to compile in my Mac (expected identifier or '{'). Is that the problem of my g++? How to upgrade it?

Comment: Try with `--std=c++11`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use C++11 with Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574246/can-i-use-c11-with-xcode)

Comment: @zneak Hi, like g++ -o --std=c++11. main test.cpp? The same error happened:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enum class` will compile if  your compiler supports `C++11` `Strongly-typed enums`.
It is available starting `GCC 4.4`
http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Answer (score 0):

http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html covers the c++11 language features and when they were supported. GCC 4.4 added the strongly typed enum support. I thought apple switched Xcode over to clang a while ago, or at least included it as an option?

Answer (score 0):

You should use clang for apple. gcc 4.2 does not support them I guess. If you want to use a more recent gcc in apple environment, take a look at [this question with its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534584/change-gcc-version-to-4-7-on-mac-os-x).