# Cannot get <random> library to work

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, c++11

I'm having trouble getting the  library working on macosx.  First off, I tried to compile the following code, saved as rand.cpp, taken from the c++ website

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
     const int nrolls=10000;  // number of experiments
     const int nstars=100;    // maximum number of stars to distribute

     std::default_random_engine generator;
     std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(5.0,2.0);

     int p[10]={};

     for (int i=0; i<nrolls; ++i) {
         double number = distribution(generator);
         if ((number>=0.0)&&(number<10.0)) ++p[int(number)];
     }

     std::cout << "normal_distribution (5.0,2.0):" << std::endl;

     for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
          std::cout << i << "-" << (i+1) << ": ";
          std::cout << std::string(p[i]*nstars/nrolls,'*') << std::endl;
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Upon running this with `g++ rand.cpp -o rand` i get the following errors

```
rand.cpp:9: error: ‘default_random_engine’ is not a member of ‘std’
rand.cpp:10: error: ‘normal_distribution’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

Searching around it seems to be suggested that the issue is the compiler, apparently thus library is only available to gcc11.  I found a way to update gcc using the macport package as shown here [Update GCC on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837992/update-gcc-on-osx) but I still don't know how to use this new compiler.  Running `g++ rand.cpp -o rand` returns the same errors even when I change the compiler with `sudo port select --set gcc gcc40` or `sudo port select --set gcc mp-gcc46`.  I also tried using `g++ -std=c++11 rand.cpp -o rand` which just returns

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Tried that also, gives `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"`

Answer (score 1):

Try it with Clang++, which should be installed in your mac, or a new version of GCC.

- **gcc42**: I had this version installed, it didn't work, and didn't recognize `-std=c++0x` and `-std=c++11`.
- **gcc49**: Installed this with `brew`, it gave the same error but `-std=c++11` made it work.
- **Clang++**: Worked like a charm without even specifying the standard (it probably defaults to c++11).

Also, check if you have the latest version of the command line tools, if not, download them from the [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-) website.

---

### What you're doing wrong

The version you installed doesn't have the `-std=c++11` option, but it should work with `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x`, that's what it says [in the manual for the 4.6 version](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options).

Comment: -std=c++11 was added in gcc-4.7.  I think -std=c++0x was added in gcc-4.3.