# Is g++ compiler the same with the gcc compiler for C++? (Mac OS X)

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

I just need to make clear one thing. In University we are learning the C++ programming language and they suggest us to use the GNU C++ Compiler which is part of the GCC. 
So on my Mac OS X Mavericks I download the ***command line tools*** from the developers.apple.com.
I wrote a simple C++ program and I compile this program using the g++ command like this:

```
g++ program.cpp
./a.out
```

And the program runs perfect. But as I know, using a different compiler, means that you have to use the correct syntax/commands/libraries for this spesific compiler, so while in the University we use the "GNU C++ compiler", I just want to make clear that with the g++ command is meant that I use the "GNU C++ Compiler".

Cheers.

Comment: you can use `g++ --version` to check if you are using GNU C++. In my OS X Mavericks, the `g++` is not `GNU C++`, it is `clang++`

Comment: `Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Programming/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix`

That's the result of the command.

Comment: same result. It's `clang++`, not `GNU C++`

Comment: That isn't exactly the same as `g++`; it is the LLVM compiler masquerading (pretty effectively) as the GNU `g++` compiler.  `/usr/bin/g++ --version` yields, for me, `Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix`.

Comment: "But as I know, using a different compiler, means that you have to use the correct syntax/commands/libraries for this spesific compiler" -- this is not quite true.  The syntax for your C++ programs will be the same whether you use Linux & G++, OS X and Clang, or Windows and MSVC.  The headers and standard libraries will also be mostly the same.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about this, if you just learn the language, you'll harldy notice the difference.

Comment: So I need to install the GNU C++ Compiler because I am going to make projects, and I want to use the same compiler as the marking computers. The teacher suggest for mac users to download the Apple's command line tools. So why is not the GNU version? :S

Comment: If you are concerned, just get the [GNU C++ Compiler](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer).

Comment: @ProgrJohn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535422/os-x-10-9-gcc-links-to-clang This will help you.

Comment: Learn the language and the programming in general. Do not worry about the minute differences between the compilers until much later. If anything, build your projects with *all* modern compilers you can lay your hands on, each set to its maximal warning level, and make sure not a squeak comes out of any of them.

Comment: @n.m. While in general yes, use any and everything.  There are benefits to students using a well defined and standard environment.

Comment: Whatever compiler you end up using at home, make sure you test your program using your school environment before you turn it in. Your instructor might be understanding the first time you turn in something that supposedly worked at home but not at school, but soon the instructor will tire of it and just take points off your score instead. The syllabus probably says it's *your* responsibility to ensure your code works in the grading environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @duskwuff, I would prefer to use `clang++`, however if you **must** be compatible, then you can installi the real GNU compiler via [macports](http://macports.org).

After installing macports (which includes a `xcode-select` step), simply do:

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
$ sudo port install gcc46
```

(or `gcc47`, etc.)

The compiler will be in your `$PATH` (if you set-up macports correctly), but explicitly, it will be `/opt/local/bin/gcc46` (see `sudo port select gcc`).

Comment: why using macports when you could use homebrew?

Comment: @rano Because macports has more ports and is less complicated WRT `$PATH` (as far as I understand it, at least).

Comment: The `$PATH` for Homebrew is easy as π: make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in there. Bam, done.

Comment: I try to install via homebrew like: `homebrew install gcc46` and the return result was that the package was missing. So I will try to install it via the macports. Cheers

Comment: After installing the gcc46 via the macport the result of the command: `g++ --version` is the same: `Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Programming/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix`

Comment: @ProgrJohn Does your `$PATH` include `/opt/local/bin` (you might need to restart `Terminal.app`)?  If so, what does `ls -l /opt/local/bin/g++*` show?  If it's not `g++` then you probably need to use `port select gcc` (google that).

Comment: `.
.
-rwxr-xr-x  4 root  admin   435492 20 Nov 22:23 g++-mp-4.6

-rwxr-xr-x  3 root  admin   431228 20 Nov 22:23 gcc-mp-4.6

-rwxr-xr-x  4 root  admin   435492 20 Nov 22:23 c++-mp-4.6
.
.`
That's the result of the command (just the lines with reference to c++ or g++, gcc)

Comment: @ProgrJohn OK, so if `/opt/local/bin` is in your `$PATH` you can invoke it using `gcc-mp-4.6` (not very attractive option), so I would use the `port select gcc` option.

Comment: I get 
`Available versions for gcc:
 mp-gcc46, 
 none (active)`
if i choose the mp-gcc46 I get an error that does not exist.

Comment: @ProgrJohn Have you seen this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837992/update-gcc-on-osx

Comment: `g++ (MacPorts gcc46 4.6.4_3) 4.6.4
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
`
Now my version is that one. Is it ok? moreover if I want to flip back to the pre-installed c++ compiler by apple what I have to do? Cheers again

Comment: @trojanfoe: I do not want to start a flame, but homebrew is REALLY macports done right : )

Comment: @ProgrJohn Yeah that looks right.  If you want to use the Apple compiler then use `clang` instead of `gcc`.

Comment: @rano I disagree.  Macports works fine for me, and has more ports, so how can it be better?

Comment: @trojanfoe how do you say more ports? never trust a program that requires sudo to do that ; )

Comment: macports is a trusted author by apple so i dont think is something bad.

Answer (score 4):

Traditionally, `gcc` and `g++` are both components of the GNU C compiler suite. `gcc` is the C compiler, and `g++` is the C++ compiler.

On current versions of Mac OS X, the commands `gcc` and `g++` are both treated as alternate names for `clang` and `clang++`, which are components of the Clang C compiler. However, this compiler is almost entirely compatible with GCC — the few differences that do exist will almost certainly not come up in the coursework you're doing.

(The most significant difference is that Clang's diagnostics are much better: it will point out exactly where  a syntax error occurs in a line, rather than just what line it's on, and it can often identify potential typos or subtle mistakes in situations where GCC would just give you a cryptic error message. If you're just learning C, you will appreciate this **a lot**.)

Comment: The stuff about better diagnostics is debatable. Now GCC also uses ASCII art to point exactly where within a line of code the error occurred. Competition is a wonderful thing :)

Comment: That true thank you! When I first compile the c++ program, I saw that the compiler highlights the errors with colors and it was more spesific on the errors rather than the gcc tha i use on Linux.

Comment: @Praetorian: As I understand it, GCC's parser is (still) not awesome at identifying the "root cause" of a syntax error - it'll tell you at what point it gave up entirely, but that may be some distance away from the actual error. I have heard that it's improving, but it's still not as good as Clang, I'm afraid!