# linking libraries and macport

Tags: macos, gcc, compiler-construction, macports

I installed gcc47 macport. Does anyone know how to link the libraries?

(I'm a noob. A detailed explanation would be appreciated.)

This is the error I get when trying to compile with just the iostream

```
In file included from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/postypes.h:42:0,
             from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/iosfwd:42,
             from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/ios:39,
             from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/ostream:40,
             from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/iostream:40,
             from practice.cpp:1:
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/cwchar:46:19: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or    directory
```

Comment: Hi. Did you run `sudo port select --set gcc gcc47`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837992/update-gcc-on-osx

Comment: If a noob - any reason why to use gcc - clang is already set up and the defaults make it easier to start with. 0also the error is not linking with libraries but a compile time error