# How do I update my g++ compiler for OSX

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, g++

I am in a class right now that requires g++ 4.7.2, however my g++ version right now is 4.2.1. Is there an easy way to update it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837992/update-gcc-on-osx